Replace column level values with tuple in Pandas dataframe
import pandas as pd

arrays = [["array_0", "array_0"], ["col1", "col2"]]
col_idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(arrays, names=["level_0", "level_1"])

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]], columns=col_idx)

print(df)

level_0    array_0     
level_1    col1 col2
0             1    2
1             3    4
2             5    6

I would like to replace the string "array_0" in column level level_0 with a tuple, e.g. (10,20,30).
Effectively, I want to replace the value of df.columns.levels[0]
Index(['array_0'], dtype='object', name='level_0')
That's what I am looking for:
level_0    (10,20,30)     
level_1    col1       col2
0             1          2
1             3          4
2             5          6

EDIT:
Clearly, this is a toy example. In real life, there might be more than two column levels, and I don't know in advance which column level I want to replace with a tuple.
Also, it might be possible that the column level I want to replace has more than one value, i.e., I have a list of tuples to replace the original values.
I am really wondering if there isn't an easy way to replace the content of df.columns.levels[x] with a list of tuples?
I was thinking along those lines:
df.columns.set_levels([(10,20,30)], level=0])

However, this leads to an error that I don't understand.
TypeError: Levels must be list-like


IIUC, you can use the following approach, replacing the column names with a new MultiIndex:
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
    (((10, 20, 30), i[1]) for i in df.columns), names=df.columns.names
)

level_0 (10, 20, 30)     
level_1         col1 col2
0                  1    2
1                  3    4
2                  5    6


You can also use pandas.MultiIndex.set_levels to achieve the same result:
df.columns = df.columns.set_levels(levels=[[(10, 20, 30)]], level=[0])

level_0 (10, 20, 30)     
level_1         col1 col2
0                  1    2
1                  3    4
2                  5    6


This works for the original question. However, it's probably not as scalable as I need it to be, especially if you don't know in advance how many column levels there will be and which particular column level you have to replace. I tried to clearify my original question, see EDIT.

@Andi I'm not sure I fully understand your clarification to the question, but in any case you can use set_levels to achieve the same result with the toy example. See the second part of my edited answer.

That's exactly what I was looking for. set_levels provides an easy way to manipulate a given column level. I wasn't aware of the fact that I have to provide a list of lists, hence the error message in my EDIT.

Just curious, is there any equivalent to set_levels if I am operating on the index (axis=0)?

@Andi set_levels is a MultiIndex method, so if your index is a MultiIndex you can use it there too: df.index = df.index.set_levels(...)

You're absolutely right! Got it. Thank you.

You can convert levels of MultiIndex to list of lists and set values like need, last recreate MultiIndex:
levels = [list(x) for x in df.columns.levels]
print (levels)
[['array_0'], ['col1', 'col2']]

levels[0][0] = (10,20,30)
print (levels)
[[(10, 20, 30)], ['col1', 'col2']]

df.columns = pd.MultiIndex(levels=levels, 
                           codes=df.columns.codes, 
                           names=df.columns.names)
print (df)
level_0 (10, 20, 30)     
level_1         col1 col2
0                  1    2
1                  3    4
2                  5    6

Another example:
levels = [list(x) for x in df.columns.levels]
print (levels)
[['array_0'], ['col1', 'col2']]

levels[0][0] = (10,20,30)
levels[1][0] = (10,20)
levels[1][1] = 'col8'
print (levels)
[[(10, 20, 30)], [(10, 20), 'col8']]

df.columns = pd.MultiIndex(levels=levels, 
                           codes=df.columns.codes, 
                           names=df.columns.names)
print (df)
level_0 (10, 20, 30)     
level_1     (10, 20) col8
0                  1    2
1                  3    4
2                  5    6

